# Adding a document to a document library

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

```
SPDocumentLibrary library = (SPDocumentLibrary)spweb.Lists["My Documents"];
SPFileCollection files = library.RootFolder.Files;
String strFilename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0].FileName);
SPFile file = files.Add(library.RootFolder.Url + "/" + strFilename, HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0].InputStream, true);
```

When setting up an immediate alert (or daily alert) for a document library, the alert is triggered as soon as a document is added to the library.

My code breaks inheritance after it adds the document, so it can change people's permissions down to the item level.

The problem comes with the alerts.  Immediate/daily alerts are sending out emails to people that a document has been added that they don't have access to.  Immediate alerts are understandable, but daily should still work correctly because I've reset the permissions before the daily alert is supposed to run.

Is there a way to setup permissions on the object before adding a document to the library?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to set item permissions on an item that didn't exist in the document library yet.

After trying to make a draft folder that no one could see, then setting the correct item permissions there, doing a copy to the root of the document library, the item permissions are not retained on the copied item.  If you do a move, the add item event for user alerts were not triggered because it's no longer new.

For this project, a custom timer job may be best suited.